# C# run windows service on different time of different timezone

Tags: c#, windows-services

Writing a windows service to run multiple times a day on different time

```
<add key="TimeZoneScheduledTime"value="UTC+04:00|06:00,UTC+05:30|08:00"/>
```

Getting time value from `app.config` file. Here i want to run the service code twice 1 at 6 am UTC+4 time zone and other at 8 am UTC+5:30 time zone.

```
 DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
 TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
           
 DateTime utcTime = localTime.ToUniversalTime();
 TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localZone.StandardName);
 DateTime convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

I am able to get the details of current system time zone. How can I convert the system time to above two timezones and run the service based on that time.?

Comment: Firstly, I'd suggest using `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of getting local time then converting it to UTC. But beyond that, it's not clear exactly which part is causing you issues. To put it another way: if time zones weren't involved at all, would you know how to schedule your code? Next, those aren't actually time zones - they're just UTC offsets. Are you certain you don't want to take DST into account, which would require having actual time zone IDs? (If you *don't* need to take DST into account, that does make life simpler.)

Comment: hi @JonSkeet DST not required here

Comment: @JonSkeet problem here is converting the time to different timezone getting from app.config.

Comment: So have you managed to parse the value from your app.config file already? That would be the first thing to do IMO. Personally I'd recommend using my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library for all of this - it's not strictly *necessary*, but I believe it'll lead to cleaner code than using DateTime etc. Given that you're not actually dealing with a time zone, just an offset, I don't think you'll need TimeZoneInfo anyway. Fundamentally if you could provide a [mcve] showing how far you've got and which step you need help with, it would be a lot easier to answer.